# Strange use of participle instead of gerund

Tags: grammar

Here is a piece of text from the book on which I'm learning English:

> Now, tell me how you've been. Just because Molly sent me here for something else, doesn't mean she'll accept **me not asking** you a few more questions.

Could you explain me (or give the name/link to a rule describing the topic), why there is that "me not asking" there? Isn't there should be "my not having been asked" instead? I.e.:

> Just because Molly sent me here for something else, doesn't mean she'll accept **my not having asked** you a few more questions.

Comment: I think you mean "my not having asked" as the been makes it passive and this is at cross purposes with the "you" rather than "by you" that follows it.

Comment: Allow me to point out (so you'll remember): explain to me, explain x to someone//an excerpt from a text in a book.

Comment: @Lambie I'd like to ask a question about your words. Is ***Allow my pointing out...*** also correct instead of your expression, ***Allow me to point out...***?

Comment: Allow me is let me. So, at the beginning of a sentence, it would not work. Let me saying....see what I mean? Let me say that [etc.]. However, it might appear as: they did allow my pointing out through my lawyer that the sale was illegal.

Comment: @Lambie Truly thank you for the decent answer. However, I still don't get why it is okay as in ***They did allow my pointing out through my lawyer that the sale was illegal*** and it is incorrect in ***Allow my pointing out that the sale was illegal***.

Comment: If you want to point something to someone, you say: Allow me to point out that I disagree with you. You wouldn't say: Allow my pointing out that I disagree with you. The set expression is: allow me to [infinitive]

Comment: @Lambie Thank you so much again, for the clarification. But, I would like to know the reason of it. What makes the two sets so different from each other in that manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just because Molly sent me here for something else, doesn't mean she'll accept my/me not asking you a few more questions.*

No is the simple answer. Both the genitive pronoun "my" and the accusative "me" are fine.

The sequence *my/me not asking you a few more questions* is a gerund-participial clause with the pronoun as subject.

The choice between genitive and accusative depends largely on style, with the genitive being characteristic of formal style (and overall relatively infrequent, I believe).

Answer (score 1):

"me" rather than "my" emphasis Molly's potential disapproval is felt to be directed at the person rather than just the lack of questioning. The former thus explains the speakers motivation more strongly.

Comment: I don't get your point. Could you put it in a more detailed way?

Comment: When "me" is used it is stronger as the object of not accepting isn't just an abstract action but also the person doing it. It's like the difference between "I don't like that you did x" and "I don't like you doing x". The latter is more likely to make the hearer take it personally and feel "(s)he doesn't like me"